# Want to float the image after minimizing the windows in html?

Tags: html, css, css-float, minimize

I am creating a webpage in which there is an image on the extreme left when the browser is maximized but as soon as the browser gets minimized i want the image to move to extreme right .. How to do that ? I tried float but it's not working..

Comment: Show your code this may [help](http://jsfiddle.net/) you.

Comment: by minimize do you mean minimized to task bar or the window is made smaller and still visible?

Comment: minimized or browser width decreased (small display screen)?

Comment: Make JS and JQuery handy to do this.

Comment: http://www.appenstien.in/website_appenstien/udi.html .. Check this page out and do check it after minimizing... @Benjamin .. after you minimize the browser window the image comes over the content.. i want it to move to extreme right.. thank you

Comment: all of you please check the above comment by me..

Comment: @AppenstienOfficial I don't see any image on that page? Do you mean the *Patrons* `<li>` Tag? Could you show some simplified code of the exact problem?

Comment: .prof
{
position : absolute;
top : 210px;
left : 200px;
}
.prof > img
{
float :left;
@media (min-width : 800px)
{
img
{
float : right;
}
}
}

Comment: It's the CSS @sven rojek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean minimized to task bar or resize window? because when you minimize to task bar the image don't visible anymore or i miss something? anyway if you mean resize so:

Use Media Queries:

```
img{
    float:right;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    img{
        float:left;
    }
}
```

This cause to image `float:right` until window's width is under 800px and if the browser's width resize to larger than 800px, the image change to `float:left`

Comment: Moshtaf : .prof
{
position : absolute;
top : 210px;
left : 200px;
}
.prof > img
{
float :left;
@media (min-width : 800px)
{
img
{
float : right;
}
}
}

Comment: the above is the css ...

Comment: <div class="prof" style="width : 240px">
  <img src="roh.jpg">
  </div>

Comment: http://www.appenstien.in/website_appenstien/roh.html ... Can you check this page.. minimize it and figure out the problem please.. it'd be a great help .. Thank you :)